# different display in same browsers, Windows - OSX

Tags: css

i have a menu bar like this:
[image]

works perfectly, but on OSX(same browser(Chrome or Firefox), same resolution) appears like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
 @media (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1920px) {

 .last-item .menu-title {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

 #leo-mainnav ul li.last-item:hover {
    background-color: #001b48;
    color: #fff;
    width: 134px;
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brfyqzqd/3/

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: talking about the font? then check the font-family

Comment: This is too little info. Re-create your problem in a working fiddle. And btw, Safari does not render the same on Windows as it does on OSX

Comment: The OSX font is narrower, so your menu items don't need all the space to right and you can see the background of the parent element.

Comment: Agree with SebastianG. I'd suggest setting the width of the menu to 100% and font-weight: 100; but we need more info to answer your question properly. Can you provide your code in fiddle?

Comment: You are probably using a specific font which is present in your Windows environment but not on OSX. Try to provide the font through your CSS, e.g. with `@font-face`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brfyqzqd/3/ and http://i.imgur.com/DNx9zvH.png
does this help?

Comment: Your CSS is too complicated/big for me to create a perfect working and looking solution, but at least you have something to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `width` in `#leo-mainnav ul li.last-item.active` and `#leo-mainnav ul li.last-item.active` to `132px` instead of `110px`.

```
#leo-mainnav ul li.last-item:hover {
    width:132px; /*So the Contactos is also centered when not hovering or active*/
}
#leo-mainnav ul li.last-item:active {
    background-color: #001b48;
    color: #fff;
    width: 132px;
}

#leo-mainnav ul li.last-item:hover {
    background-color: #001b48;
    color: #fff;
    width: 132px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brfyqzqd/7/)

Answer (score 0):

you set only border radius as like this

```
#menusys_mega {
background: url("http://portinsurance.pt/images/bg_menu.png") repeat-x scroll center top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-radius: 45px 45px 15px 15px;
box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px #888888;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0;
width: 101%;
```

}

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/4zwhs36m/)